# Free Mac MP3 player that showing playlist with large font, supports hotkeys for pause, next, etc

Tags: music, macos, media-player

I've been using VLC and Vox.

I like how VLC lets me widen the playlist as much as I want. But the font is so small.

[image: VLC]

Vox is also good except the playlist is narrow and has a small font.

[image: Vox]

What free players are available that look nice, support larger font sizes, and support hotkeys for pause, next track, etc?

It also needs to have its own volume control and the ability to shuffle a playlist of tens of thousands of tracks.

Comment: What about some custom VLC skins? Have you checked any? https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.html

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks, I can check them out.

Comment: Would a web based player do the job? Some even can play local files. In the browser, you can enlarge the view as much as you want?

Comment: Sure, I'd be curious to see one as long as it can play local files, @Marcel. Thanks.

Comment: I added Snaeplayer as an answer, since it's a good general purpose player. If you are looking for something more specific for rehearsing smaller sets of music, my own https://replayer.app might be a fit.

Comment: @Marcel Your site is impressive!

Answer (score 1):

[Snaeplayer](https://snaeplayer.com) is a web based player (as PWA) that can play from a local library.

Since it's running in a browser, you can enlarge the view like you would on any website (typically by CTRL+Scrollwheel)

Depending on capabilities of your browser, it can scan your disk for music or you must load tracks manually into it's library.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out. I like the idea.